# Is "Tout" treated as plural or singular ?

Tags: grammaire

For example do you say "Tout s'est passé bien" or "Tout se sont passé bien" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tout* is the singular form of *tous*.

> Tout s'est bien passé

That's what it would be. For the plural form, it would be something like that :

> Tous se sont bien passés.

Talking about exams, for instance.

The feminine form of *tout* is *toute*. For *tous*, *toutes*.

Edit : As some people cannot understand that the second example is contextual (regarding exams), I'll precise the fact that, *Tout s'est bien passé* ≠ *Tous se sont bien passés* (the first one isn't the singular form of the second one).

*Tout s'est bien passé* is general, just as when someone asks how your journey in another country went. *Tous se sont bien passés* in another hand, only works when someone asks you how several things (exams, previous job positions during an interview, etc) went.

Comment: "Comment se sont passés tes examens ?" - "Tous se sont bien passés". Tu peux m'expliquer à quel moment, ça "n'a aucun sens" ?

Comment: Non mais je veux juste savoir en quoi "Tous se sont bien passés" n'aurait aucun sens. Parce que c'est du bon français jusqu'à preuve du contraire. J'ai bien précisé que c'était dans un cas précis, des examens par exemple. Et la réponse dépend de la personne. Je ne vais pas dire que tous sont réussis si je viens de les passer, si ?

Comment: @Toto qu'un examen se passe bien ne veut pas dire qu'on a réussi. Si on me demande le soir des épreuves comment elles se sont déroulées, je n'ai pas encore les résultats mais je peux tout à fait répondre « Tout c'est bien passé », « toutes se sont bien passées », « tous les examens se sont bien passés ».

Comment: @Shozs: Au temps pour moi, j'ai fait une erreur d'interprétation. Je retire mes commentaires.

Comment: Aucun problème, ça arrive. :)

Comment: Tout c'est bien passé is *everything*.  Tous se sont bien passés. would be in English: *All the x* went well. x=interviews or exams, for example.